# Do LSTM in tensorflow work sequentially or in parallel

Tags: tensorflow, long-short-term-memory

I have a basic understanding how a cell and a layer of an LSTM works. However, I get confused by what "number of units" (as termed in tensorflow) exactly means. A unit is, as far as I understand one "instance" of a LSTM, consisting of $t$ cells, for a sequence of length $t$. When I have more than one unit, do these work in parallel (i.e. 10 units not interacting with each other) or sequentially (ouput of unit 1 is the input of unit 2 and so on).

Comment: IIRC a unit is a neuron.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The layer contains multiple parallel LSTM units (hidden states in tensorflow and dimensionality of the output space); they are identical and in parallel learn different things.